# Upper case HTML tags in omni completion for vim

Tags: html, vim, omnicomplete

At the moment I have to write a lot of HTML stuff (unfortunately). Vim is my favorite editor/IDE for almost everything. I'm using the 'omni completion' plugin for code completion, which works really fine with python and php. It also works with HTML, however it uses upper case HTML tags which is really annoying.

Is there a way to tell vim or omni completion that upper case HTML are completely of limits.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102859/how-to-convert-all-text-to-lowercase-in-vim

Comment: This is not the solution I'm looking for. I also want to write text with capital letters. More over this will change the case after the failure has happend. Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Unless I start the tag name explicitly with an upper case character the suggestions are always lower case. Any more info about your setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should only offer uppercase tag names if your typed tag starts with uppercase characters.

There's the following code in `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/htmlcomplete.vim`:

```
if &filetype == 'html' && exists("uppercase_tag")
```

So one workaround would be switching the filetype to `xml` (but then it doesn't know about all HTML tags, only existing in the document), or you can modify the script and put your copy to `~/.vim/autoload/htmlcomplete.vim`, so that it will override the default one.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that if the autoload script is set to use uppercase that it also lacks the newer tags for html 5. Is there an open repository of custom autocomplete scripts that are more modern that the OP might want to consider?

Comment: @Anthony: The maintainer's email address is in the script's header - go ask him for HTML 5 support (and maybe a config var to turn off uppercasing), the latest (published) version can be found in Vim's Mercurial repo.

Comment: My Q&D fix is: `sed -i '' 's/toupper(/tolower(/g' ~/.vim/autoload/htmlcomplete.vim`

Answer (score 1):

I have just found why the same issue has occured in my setup. I used to believe that it must be one of the remote plugins. In fact, it was the ignorecase option. It does not matter if you have enabled smartcase. Simply run **se noic** or **set noignorecase**.